# How to match "=" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I hava got `"icon_abc".match(/\bicon_(.*?)\b/);` worked ， which prints `["icon_abc", "abc"]`

But when I use `"icon=abc".match(/\bicon=(.*?)\b/);`, I can't get abc, it prints `["icon=", ""]`

How to match these special symbols in Javascript?  such as:  `=  -`  ?

Answer (score 4):

`=` is not a special symbol in that sense.

This would do, for example:

```
"icon=abc".match(/\bicon=(.+)\b/)
```

So would this:

```
"icon=abc".match(/\bicon=(.*)\b/)
```

You need to clarify your requirement further, so that the entire field of possible strings is covered.

Answer (score 0):

removes the ?

```
"icon=abc".match(/\bicon=(.*)\b/);
["icon=abc", "abc"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
"icon=abc".match(/\bicon=(.+?)\b/)
```

The problem is that `*` means to match zero or more of the preceding RE, and the `?` modifier makes it non-greedy, so it will return the shortest possible match. In this case, a zero-length string matches, since the word boundary is right there.

Changing to `+` means it will match 1 or more, so you won't get an empty match when it's already at a word boundary.